# carousel is jumping when i click prev or next button

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, carousel

The website is http://enspawn.com/apps/artistpalette/. when i go to the gallery section, there is a carousel. when i click the prev or next arrow sign, the carousel is going up.
I have also mentioned the code below:

```
<div class="container-fluid work" id="work">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="starts">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 work-list">
            <h2 class="text-center portfolio-text">Gallery</h2>
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <!-- Indicators -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
                  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="5"></li>

                </ol>

                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                  <div class="item active">
                    <img src="images/Start_0.png" alt="palette">
                  </div>

                  <div class="item">
                    <img src="images/Start_1.png" alt="palette">
                  </div>

                  <div class="item">
                    <img src="images/Start_2.png" alt="palette">
                  </div>

                  <div class="item">
                    <img src="images/Start_3.png" alt="palette">
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                    <img src="images/Start_4.png" alt="palette">
                  </div>

                  <div class="item">
                    <img src="images/Start_5.png" alt="palette">
                  </div>                  

                </div>

                <!-- Left and right controls -->
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev" >
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
              </div><!--myCarousel-->

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need a solution. Can anyone help me.

Comment: While navigating within the carousel, the URL changes to .../#myCarousel, which tells the browser to scroll to the element with the id 'myCarousel'.

Comment: as mentioned above on click that is the usual behavior of a link. You can stop that using event.preventDefault() if you are using jQuery http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/